# Getting failed request from PHP API

Tags: php, authentication, http

I am trying to build a back end login using PHP and SQL. I keep getting fail and I can't know why. My code:

```php
<?php
include "../connect.php";

$email = fillterRequest('email') ; 
$password = fillterRequest('password');



$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND 'password' = ? ");

$stmt->execute(array($email , $password ));


$count = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($count > 0) {

    echo json_encode(array("status" => "sucess" ));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "fail"));
}
```

I don't have enough experience to know what's the problem because the signup page worked and when I try the request using thunder client. I keep getting fail.

Answer (score 0):

'password' changed it `password` and it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).